# Set image size based on browser size?

Tags: jquery, html, css, resize, window-resize

Is it possible to dictate the size of an image/div based on the browser size when the site is first loaded?

I have the following that tells a div to be the browser size minus the content holder below however, it doesn’t work. If i take the minus bit out it works but to a random height not the height of the browser.

The main site content that appears below the header will be a flexible height as well.

Basically when you load the site the banner image should take up the whole screen regardless of browser size.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

   $(document).ready(sizeContent);

   $(window).resize(sizeContent);

   function sizeContent() {
      var newHeight = $("html").height() - $(".site_content").height()  + "px";
    $(".full_image").css("height", newHeight);
   }




});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/31gax1fk/)

Comment: title says: "Set image size based on browser size?"; body says: "Is it possible to dictate the size of an image/div based on the browser size", later: "take up the whole screen regardless of browser size". Which part of your question to trust?

Comment: vh vw http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This?:

```
function sizeContent() {
       var newHeight = $(window).height()  + "px";
        $(".full_image").css("height", newHeight);
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/31gax1fk/16/

Answer (score 0):

You could do this straight in CSS I believe with vw/vh (view-width/view-height).

Although this would distort this image, if you're just trying to make the image 20% of the browser's size (without distorting), so the browser width rather than width and height then you could just width: 20%; height: auto; in your CSS surely?

or just height: 100%; width: 100%;

Answer (score 0):

instead of specifing height and width on resize with javascript I think you may be better of using css3

```
img {
  width:100%;
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto; 
}
```

this is also responsive when the browser size changes, it automatically gives a height so the images doesn't get stretched

Comment: Needs to be a background image of a container, not a physical img unfortunately. Adding 100% width and height doest achieve this.

Comment: Then take a look at this post http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: I’m aware of that method, but it has to be the top of the site, the banner. So the main content always appears below that and you have to scroll to it. Regardless of browser size. 100% height of the div doesn’t work needs to be a set height hence JS surely?